# Do JavaScript use css styles to your webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently I have started doing JavaScript. There was a thing that was confusing me. I always heard that css is bad for the browser support and also you cannot do things with css that you can do with JavaScript. But when we use something like `box.style.opacity="0.1"` or something like this we are using the same old css to add styles. I just want to know that do functions like `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` of `jQuery` use css or something else that I don't know. If it uses something else than what is it called in simple `JavaScript` not in any helper libraries.

Comment: _"I always heard that css is evil"._ You heard wrong.

Comment: I guess.. You are in a confused state.

Comment: `I always heard that css is evil` you need to listen to different people!

Comment: *"I always heard that css is evil"*. People who is saying this must be belong to *another universe*..

Comment: @Faiz, I know you came here looking for an answer and not an advice, but here go: Please, choose better your info guys. :) keep studying as always we've to and good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions like fadeIn and fadeOut use css and the statement that css is bad is really incorrect. You should understand what is the purpose of each language: html is the content, **css is the styling and javascript is the interactivity**. You'll always use css to style your site (Or use javascript functions that do something with the css) and javascript is used for processing data, getting things from the user, calculating things, etc. Most of the sites use css and javascript.

There is an issue about browser support, but it shouldn't bother you now.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `style.opacity` and using jQuery's `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` will both alter CSS styles by changing opacity definitions.

There's nothing bad about CSS -- on the contrary, it is a integral web standard. However, there are some CSS3 definitions that aren't supported in all browsers. Check browser compatability per definition here: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)

[Can I Use 'Opacity'?](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

html is for content
css is for styling
javascript is for interactions.

Javascript can change the behavior of the page, whether it is styled with css or not.

Nothing is good or bad, it depends on implementation.